# How to embed a local video into a UIView in ios 12

Tags: ios, swift

The code I was using to embed a local video in a UIView isn't working on IOS 12. The audio is playing but I get a black screen.

from apple developer site:

Do not subclass AVPlayerViewController. Overriding this class’s methods is unsupported and results in undefined behavior.

the code works fine on IOS 11, any idea what do I need to change in the code?

thanks

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "qidong", ofType: "mp4")
        let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)


        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)


        let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
        avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)

        avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false

        avPlayerController.player?.play()
        self.view.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be subclassing in that code.  Were you doing that in before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `AVPlayerViewController` as a child view controller so something like this:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "qidong", ofType: "mp4")
       let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath!)


        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)


        let avPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        avPlayerController.player = avPlayer
        avPlayerController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)

        avPlayerController.showsPlaybackControls = false

        avPlayerController.player?.play()
        self.addChild(avPlayerController)
        self.view.addSubview(avPlayerController.view)
        avPlayerController.didMove(toParent: self)
}
```

If you are not doing that then the `AVPlayerViewController` is probably getting released early.

Another minor issue but don't use the size of the `UIScreen` but the frame of the view controllers view instead (or even better do something like use auto layout).

Comment: Glad to help out.